# Why does tar appear to skip file contents when output file is /dev/null?

Tags: tar, null

I have a directory with over 400 GiB of data in it. I wanted to check that all the files can be read without errors, so a simple way I thought of was to `tar` it into `/dev/null`. But instead I see the following behavior:

```
$ time tar cf /dev/null .

real    0m4.387s
user    0m3.462s
sys     0m0.185s
$ time tar cf - . > /dev/null

real    0m3.130s
user    0m3.091s
sys     0m0.035s
$ time tar cf - . | cat > /dev/null
^C

real    10m32.985s
user    0m1.942s
sys     0m33.764s
```

The third command above was forcibly stopped by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after having run for quite long already. Moreover, while the first two commands were working, activity indicator of the storage device containing `.` was nearly always idle. With the third command the indicator is constantly lit up, meaning extreme busyness.

So it seems that, when `tar` is able to find out that its output file is `/dev/null`, i.e. when `/dev/null` is directly opened to have the file handle which `tar` writes to, file body appears skipped. (Adding `v` option to `tar` does print all the files in the directory being `tar`'red.)

So I wonder, why is this so? Is it some kind of optimization? If yes, then why would `tar` even want to do such a dubious optimization for such a special case?

I'm using GNU tar 1.26 with glibc 2.27 on Linux 4.14.105 amd64.

Comment: As a practical alternative, consider something like `find . -type f -exec shasum -a256 -b '{}' +`. Not only does it _actually_ read and checksum all the data, but if you store the output, you can re-run it later to check that the content of the files hasn't changed.

Comment: To measure things you can also use `pv`: `tar -cf - | pv >/dev/null`. That sidesteps the issue and gives you a progress information (the various `pv` options)

Comment: You hit a well known miss feature of GNU tar. Use `gtar -cf /dev/zero ...` to get what you like.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It *is* [a documented optimization](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#file):

> When the archive is being created to `/dev/null`, GNU tar tries to
> minimize input and output operations. The Amanda backup system, when
> used with GNU tar, has an initial sizing pass which uses this feature.

Comment: Ah, this wasn't described in the man page I had installed. Should have tried `info tar` instead...

Comment: They should really keep the man & info pages in sync, it's practically a bug that they're not

Comment: @Ruslan With most GNU utilities, the man page only contains a brief summary, basically only good enough when you remember that it has an option to do something but don't remember the option's name. The complete documentation is in a format that doesn't translate well to man pages and is available with `info` or as HTML in a browser.

Comment: It's a [recognized problem](https://www.xkcd.com/912/).

Comment: It's documented, but not well explained, and I feel that surprising and un-Unixy behaviour like this deserves some justification. It's not clear why Amanda couldn't simply not call `tar` or, if it has to, for a special --do-not-write flag to achieve this, rather than (IMO) continue to break `tar` 30 years later

Answer (score 9):

This can happen with a variety of programs, for example, I had that behavior once when just using `cp file /dev/null`; instead of getting an estimate of my disk read speed, the command returned after a few milliseconds.

As far as I remember, that was on Solaris or AIX, but the principle applies to all kinds of unix-y systems.

In the old times, when a program copied a file to somewhere, it'd alternate between `read` calls that get some data from disk (or whatever the file descriptor is referring to) to memory (with a guarantee everything is there when `read` returns) and `write` calls (which take the chunk of memory and send the content to the destination).

However, there are at least two newer ways to achieve the same:

- Linux has system calls `copy_file_range` (not portable to other unixes at all) and `sendfile` (somewhat portable; originally intended to send a file to the network, but can use any destination now). They're intended to optimize transfers; if the program uses one of those, it's easily conceivable the kernel recognizes the target is `/dev/null` and turns the system call into a no-op
- Programs can use `mmap` to get the file contents instead of `read`, this basically means "make sure the data is there when I try to access that chunk of memory" instead of "make sure the data is there when the system call returns". So a program can `mmap` the source file, then call `write` on that chunk of mapped memory. However, as writing `/dev/null` doesn't need to access the written data, the "make sure it's there" condition isn't ever triggered, resulting in the file not being read either.

Not sure if gnu tar uses any, and which, of these two mechanisms when it detects it's writing to `/dev/null`, but they're the reason why any program, **when used to check read-speeds**, should be run with `| cat > /dev/null` instead of `> /dev/null` - and why `| cat > /dev/null` should be **avoided** in all other cases.

Comment: I think the implication in the GNU `tar` info page (see other answer) is that it has a special mode for this, which presumably just stats files without opening them.  In fact I just checked with `tar cf /dev/null foo*` on a couple files and yeah, just `newfstatat(..., AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW)` system calls, not even an `open()` that might update the atime.  But +1 for describing mechanisms where this can happen without having to specially detect it.

Comment: Should the mmap explanation read "access the _read_ data" instead of "access the _written_ data?"

Comment: See also `splice(2)` on Linux. Actually, replacing, `cat > /dev/null` with `pv -q > /dev/null` (which uses `splice()` on Linux) would likely reduce the overhead. Or `dd bs=65536 skip=9999999999 2> /dev/null`, or `wc -c > /dev/null` or `tail -c1 > /dev/null`...